# Object propertie undefined

Tags: javascript, object, properties

The object is ok, but when i try to access some of the properties, the properties have undefined value:

**Code:**

```
router.get('/setn', middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res){
  var aux = false;
  var arrayOfIds = req.user.following.toString();
  arrayOfIds = arrayOfIds.split(",");
  console.log("\n"+arrayOfIds+"\n");

  User.find({_id: {$in: arrayOfIds}}, function(err, foundUsers){
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
       res.status(500).send("Error finding user.")
       return;
    }
    let origLength = req.user.notifications.length;

    foundUsers.forEach(function(foundUser){
      foundUser.notiSchemaSent.forEach(function(notiSchema, i){
        console.log("\n2\n");
        if(req.user.notifications.length === 0){
           req.user.notifications.unshift(notiSchema);
        } else {
          req.user.notifications.forEach(function(userNotification){
            console.log("\n UserSchema:\n"+userNotification.username+"\n");
            console.log("\n UserSchema Title:\n"+userNotification.title+"\n");
            console.log("\n UserSchema Image:\n"+userNotification.image+"\n");
            console.log("\n UserSchema Link:\n"+userNotification.link+"\n");

            console.log("\n ====================================\n");

            console.log("\n NotiSchema:\n"+notiSchema+"\n"); 

            // OBJECT PRINT
            //{ link: '5aa42e',
            //image: '/Imgs/seholoko.jpg',
            //title: 'Test',
            //username: 'anthonyslips' }

            console.log("\n NotiSchema Username:\n"+notiSchema.userName+"\n"); //Undefined
            console.log("\n NotiSchema Title:\n"+notiSchema.title+"\n"); //Test
            console.log("\n NotiSchema Image:\n"+notiSchema.image+"\n"); //Imgs/seholoko.jpg
            console.log("\n NotiSchema link:\n"+notiSchema.link+"\n"); //Undefined

            console.log("\n ====================================\n");

            if(userNotification.link!== notiSchema.link){
              req.user.notifications.unshift(notiSchema);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });

    if (req.user.notifications.length !== origLength) {
      console.log("\n5\n");
        req.user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(500).send("Error saving user notifications.")
            } else {
              console.log("\n6\n\n");
                res.json(req.user.notifications);
            }
        });
    } else {
      console.log("\n7\n\n");
        res.json(req.user.notifications);
    }
  });
});
```

I've put some comments in the code with the values that are printed out.
I already tried to use JSON.stringify/parse, but i think it dont work because its already an object

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just do `console.log(JSON.stringify(notiSchema))`, then you can see what properties it has?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Output:  NotiSchema:
`{"username":"anthonyslips","title":"Test","image":"/Imgs/mqdefault.jpg","link":"5aa42e"}`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the deal is with `image`, but the problem with `username` is that your code is `notiSchema.userName` while the property is all lowercase: `username: 'anthonyslips'`.

Comment: Hey, `image` is printed out correctly, the problem is with `link`. And now username is ok :)

Comment: Any hint on why link is not printed ?